# Can't import from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have been using iPython notebook to use sklearn for a few months now with no problem and suddenly I can't get the command:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

to work. I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-9436dcd63a89> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

/Users/michaelreinhard/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/__init__.py in <module>()
     15 from .least_angle import (Lars, LassoLars, lars_path, LarsCV, LassoLarsCV,
     16                           LassoLarsIC)
---> 17 from .coordinate_descent import (Lasso, ElasticNet, LassoCV, ElasticNetCV,
     18                                  lasso_path, enet_path, MultiTaskLasso,
     19                                  MultiTaskElasticNet, MultiTaskElasticNetCV,

/Users/michaelreinhard/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py in <module>()
     27 from ..utils import ConvergenceWarning
     28 
---> 29 from . import cd_fast
     30 
     31 

ImportError: cannot import name cd_fast
```

I have tried a lot of different things suggested on the internet, uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda, etc., but all I have managed to do is to get the error message to change.

The interesting thing is that the command:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
```

Worked fine.

Any ideas on what my next step should be or what the problem is?

Comment: Could this post help: [Running into ImportError with sklearn while doing tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328386/running-into-importerror-with-sklearn-while-doing-tutorial)?

Comment: The function `cd_fast` is Cython code, I think. Usually `_fast` is a compiled version of something. So that looks like sklearn extensions have not been compiled.

Comment: It looks like the same problem I am having but I don't know how to implement the solution suggested. The suggested solution is to run ```python setup.py build_ext --inplace ``` or ```python setup.py install``` But when I do that I get the error message: ```python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory``` .  How do I find the setup.py file?

Comment: what python version are you running ?

Answer (score 0):

open folder /.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model and open file coordinate_descent.py and delete **from . import cd_fast** after this import error will be removed

Answer (score 0):

**!pip install -U scikit-learn**
*#if we can't exactly right install sklearn library !
#dont't make it !pip install sklearn* ☠️⚔️

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest importing the sklearn package first

```py
import sklearn.linear_model
```

and then try importing the Linear Regression

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```