# sklearn.linear_model not found in TensorFlow Udacity course

Tags: scikit-learn, tensorflow

I'm following the instructions of the Deep Learning course by Google with TensorFlow. Unfortunately I'm stuck [with this workbook](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/1_notmnist.ipynb) right now.
I work in the docker vm with all the assignment code loaded as described [here](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud730/l-6452084188/m-6560586345).

When I do all the imports everything works except for following line:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
```

it throws the following error:

```
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sklearn.linear_model
```

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17348144/3695715) sounds promising, but I did not find the source directory of sklearn.

Any help greatly aprreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install and upgrade sklearn from the shell with pip. That may or may not be the problem - but at least you'll know its installed.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

Comment: this was it, thanks for the quick, short and helpful answer!

Comment: if you're using the docker image, please exec a bash and install scikit-learn, this will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In your Jupyter notebook:

```
import pip

pip.main(['install', 'sklearn'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take note that when you are writing your code, you'll import the sklearn package using `import sklearn`, but when **installing** the package it with, say, conda, you should do the following:

`conda install scikit-learn`